# Associative array with in Associative array

Tags: php

I created an associative array within an associative array. However, I ran into a problem when I wanted to increment the pay of the elements. The PHP code is as follows:

```
$assoc_in_assoc['Manager']['name'] ="Jim";
$assoc_in_assoc['Manager']['pay'] = 7000;
$assoc_in_assoc['Manager']['Location'] ="2nd Flooe";
$assoc_in_assoc['Accountant']['name'] ="Mr Mike";
$assoc_in_assoc['Accountant']['pay'] = 4000;
$assoc_in_assoc['Accountant']['Location'] ="Account Office";
$assoc_in_assoc['Accountant']['Special Skills'] ="Charterd Accountant";

// Lets give each one a raise of 1000 dollars
foreach ($assoc_in_assoc as $rec){
echo "<pre>";
$rec['pay'] = $rec['pay']+ 1000;
echo print_r($rec);
echo "</pre>";
}// end for each
echo "<pre>"; echo "<hr/>";
echo print_r($assoc_in_assoc);
echo "</pre>";
?> </body> </html>
```

Can any one please suggest how to increment the pay with out converting the array structure?

I have solved the problem by changing the structure of the array from Associative into an Associative aray ...to an Associative array with in an indexed array.

Solution:

```
<html> <head> </head> <body> <?php 
echo "Associative array with in Associative array";

$assoc_in_assoc['0']['appointment'] ="Manager";
$assoc_in_assoc['0']['name'] ="Jim";
$assoc_in_assoc['0']['pay'] = 7000;
$assoc_in_assoc['0']['Location'] ="2nd Flooe";
$assoc_in_assoc['1']['appointment'] ="Accountant";
$assoc_in_assoc['1']['name'] ="Mr Mike";
$assoc_in_assoc['1']['pay'] = 4000;
$assoc_in_assoc['1']['Location'] ="Account Office";
$assoc_in_assoc['1']['Special Skills'] ="Charterd Accountant";

// Lets give each one a raise of 1000 dollars
$count=0;
foreach ($assoc_in_assoc as $rec){
echo "<pre>";
$assoc_in_assoc[$count]['pay'] += 1000;
$count++;
echo "</pre>";
}// end for each
echo "<pre>"; echo "<hr/>";
echo print_r($assoc_in_assoc);
echo "</pre>";
?> </body> </html>
```

Can any one please guide me to an exhaustive source of PHP array discussion? Not only the introduction but the detailed explanation of all aspects of arrays.

Comment: I made some edits that you can study to refine your English a bit :) However, this is a very localized problem that is not likely to be encountered by future visitors, so I'm closing this out. Additionally, in the future, try to avoid 'text speak' like 'plz', an unwillingness to type 'please' gives people the impression that you are lazy, which is part of the reason that you saw so many down votes. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something else to keep the same structure as before. Instead of doing a simple foreach, you can do the following :

```
foreach($assoc_in_assoc as $key => $rec){
    $assoc_in_assoc[$key]['pay'] += 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend that you read up on arrays on the PHP homepage.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

You have two options:

First off, `foreach` has two arguments! The other argument is the key for the array, which is the integer index for normal arrays, and the key for associative arrays. You can use that other one instead of keeping track of `$count` in your second example.

```
foreach ($assoc_in_assoc as $key => $rec){
  echo "<pre>";

  $assoc_in_assoc[$key]['pay'] = $rec['pay'] + 1000;

  echo print_r($rec);    
  echo "</pre>";
}// end for each
```

Second, you can make the `foreach` loop by reference and do just what you were doing.

```
foreach ($assoc_in_assoc as &$rec){
  echo "<pre>";

  $rec['pay'] = $rec['pay'] + 1000;

  echo print_r($rec);    
  echo "</pre>";
}// end for each
```